# Regex for mbb number

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I wrote a regular expression to validate mobile numbers, here is the regular expression:

```
(00966|966|\+966|05|5|9|8|0)(5|8|9)([0-9]{7,18})
```

It checks for:

1. The number must start with the following string: `00966|966|\+966|05|5|9|8|0`
2. There must be `5|8|9` after that.
3. Followed by any number.
4. ..with a length between 7 and 18.

Now, what I want is to apply an if condition, which can check if the number starts with 8, then the next number can be anything.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: [`^(?:(00966|\+?966|0?5|9|0)(5|8|9)|8)([0-9]{7,18})$`](https://regex101.com/r/HCrjfM/1)?

Comment: yup sir its working fine..thanks for help..sir can you please explain little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your regex to something like this

`((00966|966|\+966|05|5|9|0)(5|8|9)|8\d)([0-9]{7,18})`

This fulfils the condition that if a number starts with 8, then the next digit can be anything.

You can verify the results here: https://regexr.com/3tfbg

Comment: yes its fine.sir can you please explain it  |8\d .what does that mean?